# HP USB 3 Docking Station

Tags: system

the newest Version of Elementary is running on my Pavilion dv6 (HP) Notebook).Connected with an USB3 Port is the USB3 Docking Station from HP, which is not recognized. Unter Win10 Prof it is recognized and work as it should. What can I do to work the docking station under Elementary? On HP-sites there's no driver for any linux system.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I tested different docks from HP and Lenovo in my previous job, but only on Windows. Nevertheless, I know that many dock's drivers embed DisplayLink drivers. As there are drivers for Ubuntu, maybe you could try ; here is a link to download these drivers : https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu